Gnome Extensions vs Extension Manager
I've upgrated from ubuntu 22 to 24 and now I have two extension managers : Extenions 46.0 (from the GNOME project) and Extension Manager 0.5.0 (from Matthew Jakeman), I thing I've installed the last one many years ago (but do not even remember why !)

In both apps I can see the same extenions list, but I can't browse or install new ones from Extenions.
Do I have to remove Extension Manager 0.5.0 ?

I have a new install of Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. It does not contain either of the tow apps. You must have installed both at some point. You can delete either, based on your needs and preferences.

The Extensions application allows you to manage(enable/disable, remove and configure) the extensions already installed (that includes those preinstalled with the distribution and those installed later via different methods) on your machine. In order to install more, you'll need to head over to https://extensions.gnome.org/ and fist install an extension on your browser which then allows you to install extensions for gnome via that.
The Extension Manager application, however works without the need to install anything else; It allows you to manage your extensions as well as install new ones in the same place (via the browse tab).

That's not quite correct. There is no need to install extensions.gnome in the browser. Extension Manager will work quite happily without that step.

@graham you're correct, Extension Manager works without the need to install anything else. I worded that wrong in the answer.

so I can safely remove Extension Manager ?

@Sami yes, you can safely remove one or the other. "Extension Manager" is a third party application that allows to do everything "Extensions"  can do, but that also allows to search and install extensions without using the browser. Keep whichever one you want to keep.

I use 'Extension Manager' rather than the 'extensions'. I would recomment keeping 'Extension Manager' as it makes thing much simpler, you can search for new extensions with it & it manages upgrading of the installed extensions automatically.
